# How to apply Clean Architecture when Application requires Use Cases to be executed on Client and Server

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, software-design, clean-architecture

let's assume you have an application that requires application (layer?) specific logic on both, the client and the server. E.g. in case of an offline mode or CPU heavy tasks.

First: is Clean Architecture still a proper abstraction/ software architecture?

Assuming yes, I started thinking of extending the Command/Query Bus in such a way, that it could delegate those requests to the client or the server.

Would this be a proper approach?

EDIT:

Example 1: I want to annotate PDFs & model some charts always locally but upload them afterwards.

Example 2: I want to text search my locally available documents, if the remote storage is not available (e.g. no internet connection/ offline mode).

Comment: I think you need to provide some specific example in order to allow people to help you better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time has passed and our code architecture is pretty validated:

we simply chose to have the default CA project structure. Once for the client and once for the server side:

Client:

- presentation layer
- infra layer
- app layer

Server:

- api layer (is analogous to the client side presentation layer)
- infra layer
- app layer

Shared projects/layers:

- domain layer (rich domain)
- and a projects for the dtos/ error types etc (name it as you like)

Design conciderations:

- the infrastructure layer of the client handles the communication with the api layer of the server
- for that the application layer on client side defines an interface for any api command which the infrastructure layer on client side implements

Answer (score 0):

The essence of Clean Architecture is to put the (business) logic into the center of your application and push all IO to the outer most layers (circles) and then only allow dependencies from outside circles to inner circles. This way you keep your logic independent from "details" (IO, frameworks) which allows you to change those "details" later on easily and also improves testability a lot.

The principles of Clean Architecture can be applied to backend as well as frontend part of an application.

More on how to implement Clean Architecture on my blog: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture/

Comment: At the moment I have seperate assemblies for each layer.
When you say "can be applied to backend as well of frontend" do you suggest to create e.g. an application layer assembly each for the frontend and the backend respectively?
But I think the Domain should only be represented by a single assembly right?

Comment: generally speaking i would try to minimize the amount of business logic code in the frontend anyway. but if u want to/need to have logic in frontend it probably makes sense to have it an assembly separated from the actual UI. The domain model i would try to keep in backend only and if you cannot avoid using domain entities also in frontend then i would try to share the domain model assembly between frontend and backend.